Wide Character in print syswrite from net::ftpserver, ancient library & CMS bug
When i try to upload certain template files using my ancient CMS (Bricolage) virtual FTP, they fail to transfer and give the error "wide character in print". I have dealt with this forever and want to try to tackle it if anyone can help sleuth.  There is no chance the dev is going to fix this abandonware.
It seems to be a bug with net::FTPServer which has not been updated in over a decade.
Seems it's probably not expecting uft8 characters?  Can anyone see from the spot that causes the error, if there would be a way to work around it by patching this file:
Here is the exact spot:
https://github.com/pandora/Net-FTPServer/blob/42fdeca87f2092e41d68f4871253060f8e790af1/lib/Net/FTPServer.pm#L5448C1-L5448C7
Here's an excerpt from that with the last line being the one that throws the error
  while ($r = $file->sysread ($buffer, 65536))
  {
    $self->xfer ($r) if $self->{_xferlog};

    # Restart alarm clock timer.
    alarm $self->{_idle_timeout};

    if ($transfer_hook
    = $self->transfer_hook ("r", $file, $sock, \$buffer))
      {
    close $sock;
    $file->close;
    $self->_cleanup_filters (@filter_objects);
    $self->reply (426,
              "File retrieval error: $transfer_hook",
              "Data connection has been closed.");
    return;
      }

    for ($n = 0; $n < $r; )
      {
    #       $w = $sock->syswrite ($buffer, $r - $n, $n);
    $w = syswrite $sock, $buffer, $r - $n, $n;


Net::FTPServer::__ANON__("Wide character in syswrite at /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.10"...) called at /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/Net/FTPServer.pm line 5448


Always use strict; use warnings as well.

"Wide character in print" is not an error, it's a warning. Using diagnostics will tell you more:

Wide character in print at ... (#1)
(S utf8) Perl met a wide character (>255) when it wasn't expecting
one.  This warning is by default on for I/O (like print).  The easiest
way to quiet this warning is simply to add the :utf8 layer to the
output, e.g. binmode STDOUT, ':utf8'.  Another way to turn off the
warning is to add no warnings 'utf8'; but that is often closer to
cheating.  In general, you are supposed to explicitly mark the
filehandle with an encoding, see open and "binmode" in perlfunc.

Another way how to fix the problem is to encode the string.
use Encode qw{ encode };
print "\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA}";                   # This warns.
print encode('UTF-8', "\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA}");  # This doesn't.


Despite it only being a warning, it was breaking the FTP transfer...
AND i tried doing it another way:
use utf8;
$data= utf8::encode($data).. but it broke things even worse
I was expecting it to fail again but for some reason this (your) way works! :
use Encode qw{ encode };
$buffer = encode('UTF-8', $buffer);
$w = syswrite $sock, $buffer, $r - $n, $n;

( I also tried millions of versions of BINMODE and adding the utf8 layer)

It's most definitely an error even if it's not a fatal one.
